# Creating jquery draggable "stop" callbacks in a for loop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, coffeescript, closures, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a for loop iterating through a variable number of draggable elements, creating a stop-event callback for each. The callback function needs to know the index of the item that it is linked to.

I've encountered what I think is a closure problem: when the callbacks are fired off, the state of the loop iterator index variable that gets passed to the callback (_x) is the last value of the loop iterator index, rather than the value of that iterator index at the time the callback function was defined. Some coffeescript below:

```
for _x in [0..total]
  $(window).ready $(".draggable-#{_x}").draggable
    cursor: 'move'
    handle: ".draggable-image-move-button-#{_x}"
    containment: 'div#banner-builder-preview'
    stop: =>
      alert "x === #{_x}"
```

In the example above, the alert prompt will always print "x === total+1" rather than "x === 0", "x === 1"... etc.

What's the best solution to pass a unique index to the callback for each of the elements that have a stop event? I would prefer to do this without resorting to yet another jquery selector to pull more data from whatever element fired off the callback.

UPDATE:

Another problem I'm now running into: my callback, within the for loop, cannot see other functions defined in the file. I think that's very odd, even if the definition happens before the for loop is used to create the anonymous callback functions.

For example:

```
for _x in [0..total]
  do (_x) ->
    $(window).ready $(".draggable-#{_x}").draggable
      cursor: 'move'
      handle: ".draggable-image-move-button-#{_x}"
      containment: 'div#banner-builder-preview'
      stop: =>
        someFunction _x  # ... this line throws an exception, not defined
        alert "x === #{_x}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your callbacks:

```
stop: =>
  alert "x === #{_x}"
```

all end up referencing `_x` but they don't evaluate `_x` until they get called. By the time that happens, `_x` has the value `total + 1`. This is such a common issue that CoffeeScript has the [`do` keyword](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) to help:

> When using a JavaScript loop to generate functions, it's common to insert a closure wrapper in order to ensure that loop variables are closed over, and all the generated functions don't just share the final values. CoffeeScript provides the `do` keyword, which immediately invokes a passed function, forwarding any arguments.

So you can say this instead:

```
for _x in [0..total]
  do (_x) ->
    $(window).ready $(".draggable-#{_x}").draggable
      #... as before
```

Comment: Running into another strange problem... see edited question above.

Comment: That looks like another question to me and I'd need to see how and where `someFunction` is defined, maybe even a little demo on jsfiddle.net